# Export a Partial SQL on Google Cloud Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it somehow possible to Export a Partial SQL on Google Console Cloud and having this in a Command or so?

The Production SQL is around 50 GB with over 1 Million Products and a s*** load of Relations.
Stage SQL has a quite similiar Size because we test Performance in there but using this huge Database for Local Development makes everything super slow.

I would like to extract a Partial SQL From Stage or Prod ( Around 1000 Products max ).
The approach now is to Extract the Whole thing and then Delete Products Manually but this is Time Consuming ( firstly importing 50GB SQL takes too long to quickly setup a new VM and deleting 900k Products it not as funny either. )

Thanks

Comment: Is this something you are looking for?[1]

If so, then after you get the dump you can follow the process of[importing [2] that into a Cloud SQL instance.

[1]: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/is-it-possible-to-mysqldump-a-subset-of-a-database-required-to-reproduce-a-query

[2]: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#mysqldump